# Cannot scan for WiFi networks and connect to them

Tags: wifi, raspbian-stretch

I'm using Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2 with Raspbian Stretch installed. I can't use the on board  WiFi adapter. Clicking on the WiFi icon on the task bar shows 'No  wireless interfaces found'.

sudo ifup wlan0" shows "ifup: unknown interface wlan0".

Running the ifconfig and ifconfig -a commands and "sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces" shows the following.

[image: output of ifconfig and ifconfig -a]

[image: contents of /etc/network/interfaces]

I noticed that in RPi B+ model running on a fresh install of Raspbian Stretch OS , I can use WiFi. But I cannot do the same on a RPi B model with a fresh install of Stretch. This happens on other B+ and B model devices as well.

Comment: I am trying to connect my phone's hotspot. I added the ssid and pass in the etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file. I can't search for available networks.

Comment: Do not post images post text

Comment: you're using rasbian stretch ... don't mess with `/etc/network/`

Comment: Use `sudo raspi-config` go to network, wifi, and set things up there - if that doesn't work, then the only question remaining is, do you have an 2.4GHz wifi access points?

Comment: Activate your phone's hotspot. Then execute in a Terminal window `sudo iw dev wlan0 scan | grep SSID:`. Do you see the hotspot of the phone? Please address me with @Ingo, otherwise I won't see your reply.

Comment: @Jaromanda X : Yes, I do have 2.5GHz access points.

Comment: I noticed that in RPi B+ model, I can use the WiFi with a fresh install of Raspbian Stretch. But can't do the same with the RPi B model.

Comment: have you set up country code?